# Android C++ build error '__cxa_begin_catch'

Tags: android, c++, exception

Recently, I work with Android SOURCE of 4.04, I want to add my own library into external directory.

I face a problem:
when my C++ code use "C++ exception function", It builds fail.

I write a simple c++ test code, It also fail.

=========THE LOG of building ERROR:

```
test.cpp:14: undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
test.cpp:14: undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
out/target/product/bcm7231/obj/EXECUTABLES/test_intermediates/test.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTISt9exception[_ZTISt9exception]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
out/target/product/bcm7231/obj/EXECUTABLES/test_intermediates/test.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

=============The Simple C++ test is As follow:

```
//Test.cpp
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    // Test c++ exception
    int* myarray = NULL;
    try 
    {   
        myarray= new int[1024 * 128];
    }   
    catch (exception& e)
    {   
        cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    delete[] myarray;

    return 0;
}
```

============= The Android.mk is as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := external/stlport/stlport \
                    bionic \
                    bionic/libstdc++
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS :=  -fexceptions
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstlport

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

**Anyone know it？
I'm confusing about it now.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for c++ exceptions when building in AOSP, for system.

Comment: Is there a method slove this problem?Because

Comment: There is always a method if you want to go full hacker on the AOSP code (aka. you manually add exception support). The complexity of the task , on the other hand, is painful to ones mind. So in this case, Google has all the cards.

Comment: OK, 3q.  But if don't change the code google android source, How can I build C++ code using the function of exception?  You Know, most of C++ libraries use exception, change the C++ codes is not a smart way.

Comment: The runtime used by google for Android was written especially for it (aka. bionic instead of glibc). This means that if you want something that uses exceptions, you will need to use NDK. You can use NDK to build code that will be part of an image, if you want. You can generate a NDK toolchain to be able to build already existing C++ projects (with makefiles instead of Android.mk files). Just that you'd better package these libraries with an APK. Placing libraries built with NDK in /system/lib wouldn't be a nice decision from a design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a file Application.mk next to your Android.mk and add the following content:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti 
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
```

If you are building with cmake then you could add the flags to the corresponding cmake variables:

```
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
```

Comment: Currently, I build C++ code in the ANDROID source,  Not use ndk-build. I Know if use ndk tool, It's will success by Your method.

Comment: I mean that I download full android source code, and develop on it. Not build some C++ code alone using ndk tool(or other tools)

Comment: That is clear. But in order to compile the full android source code, cmake is used.

Comment: OK, I will try it use cmake.